# How can i show a message if input form is valid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor-pages

```
<input asp-for="Input.FirstName" type="text" required>
                    <span class="highlight"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <label>FirstName</label>
<span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
```

I have this code, and shows me error if input field is not valid and i want to show a text or something if input field is completed correctly. I tried to take value of ValidFirstName from here and use it in my script to change class from from hidden to block but it doesn't work:

```
@Html.Hidden("ValidFirstName", ViewData.ModelState.GetFieldValidationState("Input.FirstName"))
```

this is jquery code:

```
$(function () {
        var v = $('#ValidFirstName').val();
        if (v) {
            $("valid-field").removeClass("d-hidden");
            $("valid-field").addClass("d-show");
        }
    });
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the form is  valid,you can use `$("xxform").valid()`,here is a demo:

```
    <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" type="text" required onblur="check()">
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>FirstName</label>
    @Html.Hidden("ValidFirstName", ViewData.ModelState.GetFieldValidationState("Input.FirstName"))
    <span id="hiddenspan" hidden="hidden">valid</span>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

js:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
function check() {
            if ($("#myform").valid()) {
                $("#hiddenspan").removeAttr("hidden");
            } else {
                $("#hiddenspan").attr("hidden", "hidden");

            }
        }
```

result(if form is valid,will show the hidden span):
[image]

**Update:**

```
<div class="col-md-10">

    <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" type="text" required>
<input asp-for="Input.xxx" type="text" required>
...
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label>FirstName</label>
    @Html.Hidden("ValidFirstName", ViewData.ModelState.GetFieldValidationState("Input.FirstName"))
    <span id="hiddenspan" hidden="hidden">valid</span>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

js:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
$("input").change(function () {
            if ($("#myform").valid()) {
                $("#hiddenspan").removeAttr("hidden");
            } else {
                $("#hiddenspan").attr("hidden", "hidden");

            }
        })
```

Comment: Ok..but i don't have just one field in the form. I have to check for every field because i want to show a green tick for every field

Comment: I have updated my answer,remove `onblur="check()"` use `$("input").change(function () {...}`.